# stop carousel when video playing Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

Here is my Bootstrap 4 carousel that contains one html5 video and 2 images ,

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                        <!-- Indicators -->
                        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ul>

                        <!-- The slideshow -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <video class="img-fluid" id="video_1" autoplay loop muted>
                                    <source src="{{ asset('img_link/v.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4" />
                                </video>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="{{ asset('img_link/AdminLTELogo.png')}}" alt="Chicago">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="{{ asset('img_link/AdminLTELogo.png')}}" alt="New York">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Left and right controls -->
                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                        </a>

                    </div>
```

i need to stop sliding if video playing and slide to the next slied after video end

thnx

---

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```html
<script> $('video').on('play', function (e) { console.log('video play'); $("#demo").carousel('pause'); }); $('video').on('stop pause ended', function (e) { $("#demo").carousel(); console.log('video end'); }); </script>
```

Comment: `<video>` is an [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) so you can listen to events like e.g. `paused` or `ended` to determine when playback is paused or is done

Comment: i found this code

Comment: <script>
        $('video').on('play', function (e) {
            console.log('video play');
            $("#demo").carousel('pause');
        });
        $('video').on('stop pause ended', function (e) {
            $("#demo").carousel();
            console.log('video end');

        });
    </script>

Comment: but not working